# Can QOpenGLWidget be integrated with third party OpenGL library?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt5, sfml

Legacy `QGLWidget` could be integrated with rendering libraries (like SFML) by passing `winId()` result to the rendering library. But I can't make `QOpenGLWidget` work that way. After making it `MainWindow`'s central widget I get series of warnings like `QOpenGLWidget cannot be used as a native child widget. Consider setting Qt::AA_DontCreateNativeWidgetAncestors and Siblings.`. Furthermore, the documentation says "QGLWidget on the other hand uses a native window and surface. (...) QOpenGLWidget avoids this by not creating a separate native window.". Can `QOpenGLWidget` be integrated with third party OpenGL software at all, or is it unsupported now?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a `QWindow`, initialize it and integrate into application with `QWidget::createWindowContainer`

```
class MyNativeWindow : QWindow
{
  MyNativeWindow() : QWindow
  {
    setSurfaceType(QWindow::OpenGLSurface);
  }
};

MyNativeWindow *nativeW = new MyNativeWindow();
QWidget *w = QWidget::createWindowContainer( nativeW );
// Use w as a simple QWidget
```

In some cases you don't need to use `winId` to get `HWND`. It is enough to know OpenGL context id. For custom gl context manipulation you may use `QOpenGLContext` class.

Be careful, because if your third party libraries will create native windows (in OS X) by themselves, you will have a lot of bugs with Qt. We are tied to fix bugs in our project. (Undockable docks, keyboard focus lost, impossibility of opening menus, errors with fullscreen etc.)

You may look at this [code sample](https://github.com/dava/dava.framework/tree/development/Sources/Tools/QtTools/DavaGLWidget). And a custom context [code sample](https://github.com/dava/dava.framework/blob/development/Sources/Tools/QtTools/FrameworkBinding/FrameworkLoop.cpp).

Comment: Second link ("custom context code sample") doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Thanks alot for the code sample, this lead me on the right path. In my case, there's constant switching between two 3rd-party viewers. One of them is based on QOpenGLWidget while the other one just takes the `winId()` of a widget to do its magic. It took me almost a day of trial and error to figure out a way to enable switching between them and using their features. I put the `MyNativeWindow` object into a window container as described and, additionally to using the window's `winId()` for the 3rd-party viewer, I had to `show()` and `hide()` the parent widget (`w´ in your case) accordingly.

Comment: @FranzB. it was removed during refactoring. It is possible to get commit on 28 march for source.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov, you should link to specific commits, instead of to a branch that will change. [Like this](https://github.com/dava/dava.engine/blob/1e7c14e107e77bd3e248f3a37787876246798a0d/Sources/Tools/QtTools/FrameworkBinding/FrameworkLoop.cpp)